# UICollectionViewCell not receiving tap event, even with cancelsTouchesInView set to false

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have done some research into this because I have noticed that my custom cells are not receiving the tap event. I have an NSLog that is in place to debug when the cell has been tapped. My problem though is that the cell only receives the event on a long press. When I did some more research I found that creating a reference to the UITapGestureRecognizer and setting cancelsTouchesInView to false. After doing this it still does not receive the event except on a long press. The only UITapGestureRecognizer in the view is one set so that when the user taps outside of the menu it dismisses the menu. Have I done something incorrectly? I mean for a good UX the user shouldn't need to hold the menu option for 4-5 seconds. Here is the code:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet var menuCollectionView: MenuCollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var profileViewController: ProfileViewController!
    @IBOutlet var menuTapGestureRecognizer: MenuTapGestureRecognizer!

    @IBAction func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if (sender.state == .Ended)
        {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view
        self.menuCollectionView.dataSource = self
        self.menuCollectionView.delegate = self
        menuTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    }

    // Variables
    var menuImagesArray = ["MyProfileIcon.png"]

    // Data Source Protocol
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return menuImagesArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        var menuCell: MenuCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MenuCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MenuCollectionViewCell

        var image: UIImage! = UIImage(named: menuImagesArray[indexPath.row])

        menuCell.imageView.image = image



        return menuCell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
       NSLog("Pressed Cell")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please delete the datasource methods and instead show where you add the recognizer to the cell?

Comment: The gesture recognizer is linked in the storyboard so it is a little difficult for me to show that. But if I am understanding you correctly, do I need a separate gesture recognizer for the cell? And if so is that the one that I need to set the cancelsTouchesInView in? Currently the only gesture recognizer is the one linked to the UIView at the root as I mentioned above to dismiss the menu view

Comment: I went back to the storyboard and I had a GestureRecognizer linked to the menuCell still. I removed that connection and now it is accepting the single touch and I am getting my NSLog debug message. My problem is that now it activates the Gesture attached to the root view to dismiss the view controller.